# JAR does not exist or is not a normal file

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, hdfs

While running the wordcount example in `Hadoop`, I am facing the following error.

```
saying "JAR does not exist or is not a normal file: 
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduceexamples-2.2.0.jar"
```

My input command was :

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduceexamples-2.2.0.jar  wordcount input output
```

Comment: Have you tried `cd /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce` and then `ls`? Is the file there?

Comment: Thanks alot , that worked for me. 
though still can you explain me , where was the fault ? i am just a beginner

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just go to that path and check it out if the name is correct or not, the convention may differ by the distribution.

For example, hadoop 3.1.0 has it in the following path:

> $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.1.0.jar

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem and problem was with the version number in file. For example, in the installation instructions, the command was:

> bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-**3.2.1**.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'

While the version I'm working with was 3.1.3 so what worked for me was:

> bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-**3.1.3**.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'

Answer (score 2):

Just check whether all the dependencies are included in your jar file.
Try something like this.

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduceexamples-2.2.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar  wordcount input output
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `.jar` path can differ from distribution to distribution it's hard to say the exact path and obviously, you can cd into each directory and check, but you ever imagine there is an easy way. Just execute the following command and it will list all the jar files named `hadoop-mapreduceexamples-2.2.0.jar` with the exact location,

```
find . -name hadoop-mapreduceexamples-2.2.0.jar
```

Or if you do not know the name of the `.jar` file you can try this,

```
find . -name *.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem same, beacause I am in `/opt/module/hadoop-3.1.3/wcinput` directory.

When cd `/opt/module/hadoop-3.1.3` , and then try this again :

`hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.1.3.jar wordcount wcinput wcoutput`.

it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing this for a school project, and they had this at the bottom. A solution to our problem:
Run:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar
```

Compile

```
hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WordCount.java
```

Make Jar:

```
jar cf wc.jar WordCount*.class
```

Finally, as we were doing...:

```
hadoop jar wc.jar WordCount /user/your_name/wordcount/input /user/your_name/wordcount/output
```

Ran it, worked immediately.